# How to replace whitespace of a charArray with a String

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Java is great";
        String s1= "%20";
        char[]array=s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            if(array[i]== ' '){
                array[i]= "%20";
            }
        }

    }
```

and I need to fill whiteSpaces whit the string "%20" in a short way.

Comment: Why do not use `s.replace(" ", "%20")` ?

Comment: Are you trying to encode URLs? In that case look into [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: `char` can hold only 16 bits, which in Java usually represents either *single* character or *part of surrogate pair*. Since string contains many `char`s  you can't assign it to one `char` variable. Also you can't resize the `char[]` array. What you seem to be after is plain `s = s.replace(" ", "%20")`. But that still may be wrong solution if your *real* task is to properly encode URL like `https://server.com/file name.php?param=some value` then you should get `https://server.com/file%20name.php?param=some+value`

Comment: So maybe your example is overly simplified which could lead to [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I didnt use s.repleace(" ", "%20") because I didnt know it existed i guess... thank you for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace only spaces then use this:

`String result = s.replaceAll(" ", ""%20");`

If you want to replace all whitespaces(spaces, linefeeds, tabs etc.) use this:

`String result = s.replaceAll("\\s", "%20");`

Comment: You can use `"\\s+"` to replace any number of whitespaces with one `"%20"` if that is desired

Comment: Why would you call replaceAll when you want to replace a single space ,call replace instead of replaceAll for the single  > and you dont need to use regex \\s and can just leave it " "

Comment: @Domin0 i didnt know the existence of the method "repleaceAll", thanks dude!